# Quiero enviar un correo con la informacion de el formulario de google a un correo pero me marca que e.namedvalues no esta definido

Tags: google-apps-script

Quiero enviar un correo con la información de el formulario de google a un correo pero me marca que `e.namedvalues` no esta definido.

Lo que se esta intentando es enviar las respuestas a un correo solo con la información pedida en el formulario.

```javascript
function enviarCorreo(e) {
      var destCorreo = "jair.lopez@acrisc.com"; // Reemplaza con la dirección de correo donde deseas recibir las respuestas
      var asunto = "Nueva respuesta del formulario";
    
      var preguntas = [
        "Nombre del solicitante",
        "Área",
        "Fecha de inicio del curso",
        "Fecha del término del curso",
        "Cliente",
        "Curso",
        "Duración",
        "Modalidad",
        "Lugar de capacitación",
        "Personas a capacitar",
        "Protocolo de ingreso a las instalaciones",
        "Estatus",
        "Observaciones"
      ];
    
      var respuestas ={};
    
      for (var i = 0; i < preguntas.length; i++) {
        var pregunta = preguntas[i];
        respuestas[pregunta] = `e.namedValues[pregunta] ? e.namedValues[pregunta][0]` : "";
      }
    
      var mensaje = "Respuestas del formulario:\n\n";
    
      for (var i = 0; i < preguntas.length; i++) {
        var pregunta = preguntas[i];
        var respuesta = respuestas[pregunta];
        mensaje += pregunta + ": " + respuesta + "\n";
      }
    
      MailApp.sendEmail(destCorreo, asunto, mensaje);
    }
```

Comment: Hola Teniente, deberías subir la sección del código, donde llamas a **enviarCorreo**, que es donde se genera el error.

Answer (score 0):

En el código proporcionado, el error "e.namedValues no está definido" ocurre porque se está intentando acceder a la propiedad e.namedValues incorrectamente. Para solucionarlo, debes modificar la forma en que accedes a los valores de e.namedValues.

Aquí está el código corregido:

```
function enviarCorreo(e) {
  var destCorreo = "jair.lopez@acrisc.com"; // Reemplaza con la dirección de correo donde deseas recibir las respuestas
  var asunto = "Nueva respuesta del formulario";

  var preguntas = [
    "Nombre del solicitante",
    "Área",
    "Fecha de inicio del curso",
    "Fecha del término del curso",
    "Cliente",
    "Curso",
    "Duración",
    "Modalidad",
    "Lugar de capacitación",
    "Personas a capacitar",
    "Protocolo de ingreso a las instalaciones",
    "Estatus",
    "Observaciones"
  ];

  var respuestas = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < preguntas.length; i++) {
    var pregunta = preguntas[i];
    respuestas[pregunta] = e.namedValues[pregunta] ? e.namedValues[pregunta][0] : "";
  }

  var mensaje = "Respuestas del formulario:\n\n";

  for (var i = 0; i < preguntas.length; i++) {
    var pregunta = preguntas[i];
    var respuesta = respuestas[pregunta];
    mensaje += pregunta + ": " + respuesta + "\n";
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(destCorreo, asunto, mensaje);
}
```

En la línea respuestas[pregunta] = e.namedValues[pregunta] ? e.namedValues[pregunta][0] : "";, se utiliza el operador ternario (? :) para verificar si existe un valor para la pregunta en e.namedValues. Si existe, se asigna el primer valor de e.namedValues[pregunta] a respuestas[pregunta]; de lo contrario, se asigna una cadena vacía ("").

Espero que esta corrección solucione el error

Comment: Agradezco la ayuda pero por alguna razón continua el error, no se a que se deba llevo dos dias averiguando que esta pasando

Comment: @AsterionArsenio a que otra causa le atribuyes el problema?